# Hiding user control properties from IntelliSense

Tags: .net, visual-studio, intellisense

How can I hide user control properties from IntelliSense in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply the [`[EditorBrowsable]` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx). It's still possible to the developer to show these hidden members via the VS Options dialog, however.

Comment: Very good, now i'd like to hide the Inherited class properties like size property of form class. thanks for your answer.