# Why EditorBrowsable doesn't work?

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried to hide inherited property in intellisense with `EditorBrowsable` (as said here [Hiding user control properties from IntelliSense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852164/hide-usercontrol-properties-from-intellisense)), when testing in client form though I can still see it why ?

```
[
Category("Main"),
Description("Text"),
Obsolete("Don't use this"),
Browsable(false),
EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)
]
public override String Text
{
    get { return null; }
}
```

Comment: Few years passed, but for anyone interested: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4434

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I repro.  There is a Note in the MSDN article about this:

> In Visual C#, EditorBrowsableAttribute
>   does not suppress members from a class
>   in the same assembly.

Oddly, I don't see it suppress it either when I put the `UserControl` in a different assembly in the same solution. 
  You may want to ping [connect.microsoft.com](http://connect.microsoft.com/) about this, something isn't right.

Comment: did you close and reopen VS? VS caches controls.

Comment: at least you seem to have same result as me so i'm not crazy :) Will give up too irational for me !

Comment: Few years passed, but for anyone interested: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4434

Answer (score 45):

Are you using ReSharper? It seems like ReSharper doesn't *obey* the `EditorBrowsable` attribute.
 If I turn off ReSharper, I don't see my property. If I turn ReSharper on, it *does* show.

In ReSharper Options, go to [Environment | IntelliSense | Completion Appearance](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Options__Environment__IntelliSense__Completion_Appearance.html) and check "Filter members by [EditorBrowsable] attribute".

You still have to reference the assembly though, it doesn't work within a solution if you reference your usercontrol's project.

Comment: No I'm not using Reshaper. I have opened the client project in another solution and point to the dll from toolbox and I can still see Text property in intellisense. I think I'll give up seems too irational for me :)

Comment: that worked for me, as I am using resharper. Even with the same solution when referenced as a project it works. thank you!

Comment: Thanks! After hours trying to make it work, I read your answer and voilá! Works flawlessly now. Thanks, I'd never thought resharp was causing it.

Comment: To me it seems like Resharper can actually enforce obeying of this attribute where VS does not. If I disable Resharper, the attribute does not work - only when I enable Resharper and set this filtering, then it works. Verified in 2015 and 2017.

Answer (score 15):

As said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9086419/2498426)'s comments:

> editorbrowsable only hides the method if you're just importing the dll, not if you're referencing another project in the solution i think

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this:

Visual Studio > Tools > Options > General > Hide Advance Members

Check the "Hide Advance Members", remember that, in Visual C#, EditorBrowsableAttribute does not suppress members from a class in the same assembly.

[EditorBrowsableAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: this solution not working for me in VS2019