# Hide namespace from IntelliSense or change order of suggested namespaces (Customizing IntelliSense)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces, intellisense

I'm writing a dll in VisualStudio. This library contains two classes with the same name but in different namespaces.

```
public namespace XCharting {
    public class Series { }
}

public namespace ObjectModel {
    public class Series { }
}
```

Users of my library use first one. Other one is used in other my dll (In future it is possible that users will need the second class too).

The problem is when users write "Series" in their code. IntelliSense suggest to add 
1)ObjectModel namespce
2)XCharting namespace

Is is tossible to change an order of suggestions or hide suggestion of adding ObjectModel namespce?

Comment: [hth](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9086419/815938)

Comment: Attributes can not be attached to namespaces. It's better to change order of suggestions if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It  seems  it  is  impossible.